# what is .schema files in openLDAP

Tags: schema, openldap

what are files in `/etc/openldap/schema/` that sometimes included in slapd.conf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It the schema of you Directory. It defines a set of rules, which specify types of objects a directory may contain and the required and optional attributes entries of different types should have. A LDAP schema may also specify the namespace structure and the relationship between different types of objects. I think you need to [read a bit more on how a directory works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenLDAP).

I hope it helps.

JP